# Is it easier to scale the database using Rails or Django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, scaling

When creating a Saas product, the database is the biggest issue when it comes to scaling.

From my research, it seems Django provides a more built-in robust way to vertically partition the database.

Rails has some gems that you can use, but its not something that ships with the Rails framework and your really at the mercy of the developer who released it (and may not be keeping it up-to-date etc.)

In terms of vertical partitioning, is my observation correct that Django is more robust in this area?

Multi-dbs using django: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 3):

You can do multiple databases in Rails, each model can have a separate connection if you want, this is part of the core functionality, but this is not going to be a very effective way to scale. It is usually much better to focus efforts on tuning your database stack by adjusting settings, clustering, replicating, or by applying more rigorous caching within the application itself.

Splitting tables across databases is really not going to buy you much scalability. A more modern approach is sharding where each table is split into separate instances, though to go down this path requires both significant preparation and a very solid understanding of database architecture. Since you can control the size of each shard, you can scale without limitation in this regard.

Keep in mind that Rails ships with ActiveRecord as the standard Object Relationship Mapper (ORM) but there are two other production-ready packages which offer different features: [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) and [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/)

In my experience with developing large-scale applications, the only time you will find the database to be a bottleneck is when you're using a poorly tuned configuration, an under-powered piece of equipment, or your table structure isn't sufficiently indexed or de-normalized. This is common to all database-backed applications and isn't unique to Rails or Django, so your choice of platform is really not relevant here.

Most of the performance gains in a Rails application come from proper data de-normalization, use of `Rails.cache` backed by memcache, and switching from model-based loads to direct queries where necessary for performance reasons. Rails can scale very well on a single database instance with nothing especially exotic in terms of techniques, just thorough application of basic optimization principles.